# How to implement iOS Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I just have a question and can't seem to find it anywhere.

I"m new to iOS development and trying to use Google Maps inside my application.

I went thru the example they give you [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#add_a_map).

```
    #import "DemoViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation DemoViewController {
  GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)loadView {
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285
                                                          longitude:103.848
                                                               zoom:12];
  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  self.view = mapView_;
}

@end
```

But as you can see the they set `self.view = mapView_;` and the UIView class doesn't have a view function.

I want the map to be inside a UIView I have that is inside another ViewController

Did I lose you yet? Either ways here is a picture.
[image]

So inside of the view (or whitespace) I want the map to load.

Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: I just tried whatever they provide which is an example where you make a ViewController and load the map. (Updated above)

Comment: you can add your mapview as a subview? 'self.view addSubview:mapView'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me if anyone needs to do something similar.

I just used a container view and then made separate `UIViewController` class (that has the [google maps sdk code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) add a map section) and then hooked it up to my main ViewController by using **`[self.view addSubview:googleMapsView];`** googleMapsView being my container view that I connected to the main ViewController.

Answer (score 6):

So you've got a GMSMapView. And you can make one view a subview of another in the interface with `addSubview:`. I wouldn't do it in `loadView` if I were you, though. `viewDidLoad` is the earliest good opportunity.

I think your real problem is that you're way ahead of yourself. You're trying to do this without know how views work, how view controllers work, etc. I recommend you take a deep breath and learn about iOS programming before you jump in with all four feet. Otherwise you don't know what your code (or Google's code) even means.

Comment: You're right that I need to learn more and that's why I asked. I just want to know the best way to go about doing this would be.

Comment: Well, I think I answered that. You need to know about views and subviews, getting a reference to a view through an outlet, loading a view controller's view and using an instance variable to refer to the outlet, and so on. That's all basic iOS programming stuff; it has nothing to do with Google Maps. When you know all that, how to put a GMSMapView into your interface will be dead obvious.

Comment: @matt: on a different note, do you happen to know how well google maps based apps are approved by Apple ? I am not sure with this.

Comment: I've no reason to think Google is doing anything here that's against Apple's rules. Apple could apply their rules arbitrarily at any time, but nothing you have to do in order to use the Google API seems to be against the rules; it's all straightforward above-board stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I did an exact same thing [here](https://github.com/kaskaderc/ios_samples/tree/master/MapWithZoomInOutButtons).

Simply added a View of type `GMSMapView` via interface builder and then set up the properties in  controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try below code.
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
-(void)addAllPinsOnMapView
{
arrMapPin=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < arrOfferList.count; i++)
{
    GMSCameraPosition *cameraPosition=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[[[arrOfferList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue] longitude:[[[arrOfferList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue] zoom:12];
    //    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:cameraPosition];
    _mapView.camera = cameraPosition;
    _mapView.myLocationEnabled=YES;

    GMSMarker *marker=[[GMSMarker alloc]init];
    marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[arrOfferList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue], [[[arrOfferList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]);
    marker.title = [[arrOfferList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"business"];
    marker.map=_mapView;
    _mapView.delegate = self;
}
}
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:
(GMSMarker *)marker {
NSPredicate *result;
result=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"business CONTAINS[c] %@",marker.title];
NSArray * array = [arrOfferList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:result];
OfferDetailsViewController *objOfferDetailsViewController = [[OfferDetailsViewController alloc]init];
objOfferDetailsViewController.dictOfferDetails=[array objectAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objOfferDetailsViewController animated:YES];
}
- (IBAction)btnLocateMe:(UIButton *)sender
{
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[[[AppDelegate initAppDelegate].DictLocation objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue] longitude:[[[AppDelegate initAppDelegate].DictLocation objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue] zoom:14];
[_mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.